# Is it possible somehow to replace original object that is argument to a function?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference

```
function f(obj) {
    obj = _ => console.log(
        'LOCAL object was replaced, how to replace from the outer scope?');
}

f(fetch);
```

As I understand this is impossible, but maybe some trick exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that.

Instead, your best bet is to *return* the new object, and reassign when calling:

```
function f(obj) {
    return _ => console.log(
        'LOCAL object was replaced, how to replace from the outer scope?');
}

fetch = f(fetch);
```

---

Alternately, you can pass in a container that has the target object as a part of its state, and update the state of that container:

```
function f(container) {
    container.obj = _ => console.log(
        'LOCAL object was replaced, how to replace from the outer scope?');
}

var c = {obj: fetch};    
f(c);
// ...use c.obj...
```

or

```
function f(container) {
    container[0] = _ => console.log(
        'LOCAL object was replaced, how to replace from the outer scope?');
}

var c = [fetch];    
f(c);
// ...use c[0]...
```